# Vuetify - How to select a row data using v-radio-group in v-data-table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to select a radio button in a row but if i select one in a row it is automatically selecting other in that row.
Sample [`Example`](https://codepen.io/santhikumar43/pen/qBOQLGO?editors=1010)

This is how the radio button code in table data.

```
<v-radio-group v-model="selected">
  <v-radio :value="props.item.name" :label="props.item.fat"/>
</v-radio-group>
```

What i wanted to do here is, in the above example there are 2 radio buttons in each row, i just wanted to select only one radio button per row. It seems it is working like a column level selection instead of row level selection. How can i make this as a row level selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, there are two things that stop it from working as you would like.

First: get rid of `@click="selected = props.item.name"` as this is is triggering click on the row.

Second: you are binding `<v-radio-group v-model="selected"` to selected in both columns. You have 6 radio buttons but only 3 items. This is where the mistake is. If you split selected into two groups (selectedCalories and selectedFat) such as:

```
 <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
          <tr >
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">
            <v-radio-group v-model="selectedCalories">
              <v-radio :value="props.item.name" :label="props.item.calories"/>
            </v-radio-group>
            </td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">
            <v-radio-group v-model="selectedFat">
              <v-radio :value="props.item.name" :label="props.item.fat"/>
            </v-radio-group>
           </td>
        </tr>
      </template>
```

It will work as you wish.

Remember you will need now two references in your data:

```
selectedCalories: [],
selectedFat: [],
```

---

UPDATE:

To select only one in a row, value needs to be different between `v-radio` such as:

```
<template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
          <tr >
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>

          <td class="text-xs-right">
            <v-radio-group v-model="selectedCalories">
              <v-radio :value="props.item.calories" :label="props.item.calories"/>
            </v-radio-group>
            </td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">
            <v-radio-group v-model="selectedFat">
              <v-radio :value="props.item.fat" :label="props.item.fat"/>
            </v-radio-group>
           </td>
        </tr>
      </template>
```

You will still need two selected items in data:.

```
    selectedFat: [],
    selected: [],
```

---

UPDATE - select one per row:

```
<template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
          <tr>
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>

          <td class="text-xs-right">
            <v-radio-group v-model="props.item.selected">
              <v-radio :value="props.item.calories" :label="props.item.calories"/>
            </v-radio-group>

          </td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">
            <v-radio-group v-model="props.item.selected">
              <v-radio :value="props.item.fat" :label="props.item.fat"/>
            </v-radio-group>
          </td>
        </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi, I modified accordingly, but in this case i am able to select the calories and Fat in a row right? It has to work like to select either calories or Fat, only one per row.

Comment: What i see is, which your changes, i am able to select only one Calories and one Fat through out the data. But what i need is to, i can select multiple calories or multiple fat but only one in a row(either calories or fat).

Comment: Please take a look at the code pen https://codepen.io/santhikumar43/pen/qBOQLGO?editors=1010 , i have updated accordingly. But it seems not working. Let me know if i miss any thing.